# actionUpdate on Multi Model form

Tags: php, yii

How can I update through a multimodel form in Yii?

If my create action is

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Model;
    $model2 = new Model2;
    $model3 = new Model3;
```

Normally in update action I will use

```
public function actionUpdate($id) 
{
    $model = $this->loadModel($id, 'Model');
```

But how to I handle the others models (Model2 and Model3).  I want to be able to update all models at the same time.

Comment: What's the problem, exactly? You should be able to update similar to how you did the create. Have a look [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/19/how-to-use-a-single-form-to-collect-data-for-two-or-more-models) and the link in that article. If you want to use a single model, you would probably have to create it (and all the validation rules, etc.) yourself.

Comment: @ldg, I have many multimodel forms that I am using and create just fine.  However I have not been able to work out the updates.  In an update you load the id of the model you are updating.  But how do you load the associated models?  If I put in `$model2 = new Model2;` in the update I get integrity constraint errors in my db since it is trying to create a new Model2 when I just need to update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you update your "loadModel" method to use different models, something like:

```
public function myLoadModel($id, $m='Model')
{
    $model=$m::model()->findByPk((int)$id);
    if($model===null)
        throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
    return $model;
}
```

And use that for your update functions.

Comment: no I definitely did not try something like this.  After seeing the code you posted I know understand the reasoning.  Using a variable for the model is not accepted though.  I get an error on `$m::model()`.  Also since I will need to grab a record in the associated table by the FK of the main table is this going down the right path?  With the findByPK I think it will be grabbing the PK of the associated table instead right?  Sorry for all the questions but I want to make sure I understand what is being accomplished and since I don't have any code to t/s with yet I am a bit lost.

Comment: which version of PHP are you using? that class variable should work in ~5.2+. If you aren't passing the PK, you can use `findByAttributes()` and pass the column and value for each model.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
This is how I solved it:

```
public function loadModel($id)
{
    $model=Model::model()->with('model2', 'model3',...)->findByPk((int)$id);
    if($model===null)
        throw new CHttpException(404,'Page not found.');
    return $model;
}
```

Hope it to help you.